# Toolbox overlaps Form Designer in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022, windows-forms-designer

I'm having a problem trying to move the design form window in visual studio, Picture
[image: here]
The designing window is on the top left, The reason is the space, another picture is
[image: here]
As you see, When I open the toolbox, It doesn't let me view the window anymore, while there is a huge unused space, It'd be really great if I can move the designing form to use all of the space I have on my monitor

I have tried googling a lot for this problem, I haven't found any problems matching to mine, It might be a very stupid simple thing, But I have no idea, or at least I googled unmatching keywords to the other people that had the same problem

Comment: What about moving the Toolbox to the right side of the IDE? BTW, you don't need to *see* the Form to add a Control to it from the Toolbox

Comment: It'd be better if the window goes to the empty spaces, It's just empty useless space there, And I can't see whole window if I open toolbox

Comment: Should the Form be, let's say, centered on its container, there would be still empty space, just around it :) Is there a problem with moving the Toolbox to the other side, if its current position bothers you? You can also keep it pinned and double click a Control to add it to the active Form. You cannot move the Form, but I really cannot see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the fixed key to dock the toolbox pane so it doesn't overlap the form designer.

[image]

Or as @Jimi said, drag and drop the toolbox pane somewhere else.

If you accidentally close it, you can find it in view->toolbox

Comment: Worked for me, I appreciate your answer, I tried to upvote but I couldn't due to me not reaching the sufficient requirements of reputations

Comment: I did so @JialeXue